# When and How can a child kill? (Fork)

Tags: c, fork, systems-programming

I'm wondering that, when I'm using fork and creating several children and then the children are creating several children.

What should I do when a child finishes its task?

```
void foo(){
    pid_t childpid = 0;
    .
    .
    .

    while (..){

        childpid = fork();

        if ( childpid == 0)

            if(...)
                foo();
            else
                /* Do something */


    }
    while(wait(NULL) > 0);

}
```

This is very basic code because I'm trying to learning fork mechanism.

The question is:  When the child's task is completed, what should I do? Should I use `exit(0)` for kill him or `break`?

If I use kill, valgrind gives me `still reachable`; if I use break, the process does not die and returns to the main function.

And second question: if child into first if condition, it calls foo again. Then there is a children in it. Should it wait or not?

What should I do?

Comment: You exit the child process like you exit the main process: Either by returning from the `main` function of by calling `exit`. If you don't want the child process to continue the loop in your `main` function, then a call to `exit` seems appropriate.

Comment: The recursive calls to `foo()` need to be coded with care — it isn't a common practice, but it might be correct for a given problem.  (In my experience, it is much more likely incorrect than correct, but you might have a legitimate use case for creating children recursively.)  If you're getting reports of leaked memory when you exit, you could arrange to call the clean-up code before calling exit so that memory is freed and files closed, etc.   As to waiting, again, it depends on what is the desired behaviour.  Note that a process can only wait on its own children, not on grandchildren.